# navigator.useragent reference lost in closure compiled js

Tags: javascript, closures, google-closure-compiler

I was using a simple regex test like

```
is_safari_or_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

in my js. After compile it with Closure compiler (advanced optimization) it's not working anymore. It still give me the regex but navigator.useragent is missing.

Note, I'm not using closure library and do no intent to use at this point. How can I preserve this test?

**js code**

```
var browser_type = new RegExp('(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit', 'i');
function is_safari_or_uiwebview() {
    return browser_type.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
window['is_safari_or_uiwebview'] = is_safari_or_uiwebview;
```

**compiled code**:

```
var l=/(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i,l=/(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i;function m(){return l.test(navigator.c)}window.is_safari_or_uiwebview=m;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: Use bracket notation, [as explained in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?csw=1#propnames).

```
navigator['userAgent']
```

BUT, when I test your code in http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home, it does *not* rename the property name with advanced compilation.

Comment: thanks! did not got this exact idea from there. now it works.

Comment: Sounds like some externs are missing, because that property should not be renamed like that.

Comment: @Chad: I was thinking the same. I thought that the compiler includes those "standard" externs by default.

Comment: @FelixKling It does - but there are options to disable that such as `use_only_custom_externs` or by using a custom build of the compiler.